# How are ransomware keys found?

Tags: ransomware

I'm familiar how ransomware works and how they encrypt the files.

If the encryption is done by a public key only (which the private is saved at the attacker's server), you cannot decrypt those files unless you receive the private key.

Which common bugs/backdoors the public decryptors found in the ransomware to be able to decrypt the files successfully? (https://www.nomoreransom.org/decryption-tools.html)

I can think about several - for example, if the encryption key is symmetric - one can try and catch it in ransomware's memory before it encrypts the file and use it to decrypt the rest afterward.

Comment: some keys are published by the ransomware authors

Comment: the private ones? why? what's in it for them?

Comment: Google "ransomware keys released" - you will get a whole bunch

Comment: It's pretty odd that ransomware will use a predefined set of keys to encrypt. the better approach is to actually construct it on the fly, and save the private key aside.
i'm guessing they didn't do it because it consists much more work? (managing a different key per successful attack?)

Comment: Ransomware infections are opportunistic - you don't know who you will infect, or when. If it is a worm, then you really do not know. How would you get the key under your control?

Comment: Well, Let's assume after successful payment the key is sent for decryption - which means, if it's global - it can be used for several more decryptions (maybe the attackers don't care, as they can modify the programs quickly).
i'd think of a "perfect" Ransomware is to get the public key (generated) from the malicious server, then with the payment - you will have to provide an ID that is used to receive your own personal decryption key.

if the attackers don't intend to send back the key after payment, then i understand.

Comment: I've also talked with a friend, he mentioned another interesting approach - the attacker constantly generates new instances of his malware with embedded public keys, thus when someone downloads it, it probably receives a special instance of that malware (not requiring even a server).

interesting, i think i got the info i needed, thanks!

Comment: @ArielB What's in it for them? Ransomware authors are not sociopaths (well, not all of them), they are just criminals. If they are shutting down operations, it's the "polite" thing to do to release the keys.